# How to constrain cumulative Gaussian parameters so that the function will intersect one given point?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization, probit, constraint

I am analyzing data from one study where participants had to choose (between two stimuli) the one with higher intensity. One way to look at the data is to fit the proportion of correct choices as a function of the absolute difference between the 2 intensities (let's call it delta $\Delta$).

This gives me a function that predict the probability p of correct choice for any value of  $\Delta$. I use a cumulative Gaussian function, scaled so that the predicted probability is between $0.5$ (chance, meaning pure guessing) and $1$. Below there is a plot of a sample of data.

The problem is that often the best fitting function predict a probability higher than $0.5$ even at $\Delta=0$, which does not make much sense. The function should approach $0.5$ as $\Delta$ approach $0$, because for very small values of $\Delta$ participants are necessarily at chance (that is $lim_{\Delta\to0}p=0.5$).

I would like to constrain the parameters so that the function will pass in $(0, 0.5)$, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help with this?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Please note that the desired function needs to predict a probability between 0.5 and 1 (probability of correct choice cannot be less than chance here), and that it needs to have both location and scale as free parameters. This is required to account also for cases where (differently from the plot below, which is presented only to demonstrate the problem stated above) the proportion of correct choices stays at chance until quite large values of $\Delta$ and then increase rapidly (with slope similar as the plot below or even more steep).**

**It doesn't have to be necessarily a cumulative Gaussian, also another sigmoidal function could work (if using another function makes it easier to put the constraints).**

[image]

I use `R`, and this is the code I use for fitting. This gives the cumulative Gaussian function, scaled so that the lower asymptote is at 0.5:

```
pnorm2AFC <- function(x,...){
    0.5 + 0.5*pnorm(x,...)
}
```

and I use this to compute the negative log-likelihood. `d` is a dataframe with the number of correct and error responses (`nnyes` and `nno`) for each values of delta. `p` here indicates the parameters (mean and standard deviation).

```
lnorm_2AFC <- function (p, d) {
    -sum(d$nyes * log(pnorm2AFC((d$delta - p[1])/p[2])) 
        + d$nno * log(1-pnorm2AFC((d$delta - p[1])/p[2])))
}
```

Then I find the parameters using `optim()`

```
par <- optim(par = c(0.2, 0.2), lnorm_2AFC, d= data)
```

Comment: The Gaussian (or perhaps it's an Error function, if it truly is cumulative) looks like a poor fit.  Why not use logistic regression?  Constraining that to go through $(0, .5)$ is easy: simply drop the constant term.

Comment: the problem with using a logistic without constant term (if I understood correctly) is that it would not be "s-shaped" (not for positive values of $\Delta$), so it would be a poor fit for cases where the proportion of correct choices stay at chance for a large range of $\Delta$, and increases only for very high values

Comment: about the fit, yes it is cumulative (basically is a glm with probit link, only that the predicted probability is scaled between $.5$ and $1$) and the data are averaged in bins only for the plot (identical values of $\Delta$ are actually rare) so I think is difficult to judge the fit simply from the plot

Comment: What do the size of the circles represent?

Comment: Assuming, as you write, that the response is proportions of correct choices, then the graph alone is enough to demonstrate a poor fit. What you need to recognize is that a given discrepancy between data and curve has a different meaning depending on the elevation of the curve. The model you are proposing will not deal with that correctly. If you're interested in good results (and not just a nice-looking fit), then I recommend editing this post to explain your data better and to describe the motivation for the shape of the curve you are suggesting.

Comment: @Glen_b the size of the circles is proportional to the number of observations in that bin. Circles are placed at the average values of delta of that bin. The actual values of delta are uniformly distributed; I plotted data average over bins only because otherwise it gets too cluttered.

Comment: @whuber I edited the question, hope it is more clear. The discrepancy is larger around 0.5 proportion correct, where binomial variability is also larger. Why this would be a problem specifically for the model that I am proposing?

Comment: You might also be interested in [isotonic regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) as an alternative solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found one solution to my question so I will post it here.

One way to constrain the function to pass in $(0, .5)$ is to use a cumulative [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) function instead of a cumulative Gaussian. The Weibull is defined only for positive values, so that at $0$ the predicted probability is necessarily $0$. When scaled as described in the question above, the predicted probability at $0$ will be necessarily $0.5$.

Comment: More generally, for whatever function and parameterization you're fitting, you can use constrained optimization software to impose constraints, such as forcing the fitted equation to go through a specific point, or constraining parameters being fitted (i.e., optimization variables) as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how to impose this kind of constraints in R?

Comment: I'm not an R person, so I will not vouch for this, but you can look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alabama/alabama.pdf . You may not find it easy to use.  Given the state of affairs, MATLAB or OCTAVE are a much better environment nowadays for optimization than R.  If you have no experience in optimization (and I'm not talking gradient descent crap), you may not find it an easy go.  A forum comment is no substitute for taking a course.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just fit a probit GLM without intercept?

Then $E(Y) = \Phi(0+b\Delta)$ and

$E(Y|\Delta=0) = \Phi(0)=0.5$.

Isn't that a solution to the posted problem?

---

Here's a plot for a model I fitted by transforming $p$ using an inverse normal cdf ($y=Φ^{-1}(p)$), then fitting a linear regression with no constant term, then transforming back:

[image]

It, too satisfies the conditions mentioned in the question

Comment: yes it is a solution, but it doesn't fit well cases where the proportion of correct choices stays around  $0.5$ until relatively large values of $\Delta$. In these cases the derivative of the best fitting function should increase and then decrease, so it would be better to have the whole sigmoidal curve over positive values of $\Delta$, not only half of it (I should have stated this point more clearly in the question, sorry). This can be done with my solution of using a cumulative Weibull function.

Comment: My answer is a solution to the problem you have posted. If you want a solution to a different problem, why not post that one? i.e. Why isn't this information that alters what you asked in your question?

Comment: The question was how to constrain a specific function, one that predicts probabilities within 0.5 and 1 (i.e. it has the lower asymptote at 0.5) to go through (0, 0.5). You proposed the same approach that @whuber proposed in his comment (use a GLM without constant term), which results in a different function with a different shape (is not sigmoidal anymore over the range in which my variable $\Delta$ takes values), and involves a loss of generality (it cannot fit correctly other cases, for example the one I illustrate in my previous comment)

Comment: I don't understand your response at all. Your question - quite explicitly - seems to be asking for a way to make the fit pass through (0,0.5) (which I did).  Now you seem to contradict that explicit request by claiming you actually want a curve that asymptotes to 0.5. Unless you plan for it to dip below 0.5 and come back up again, the two are contradictory'; it can't be monotonic (e.g. S-shaped) and pass through y=0.5 and also asymptote to it. I expect you mean something different from what you've said, which will probably necessitate a change to your question.

Comment: Note further that your question asks for "cumulative Gaussian", which my solution is, but yours is not. Again, if you want something different from what you asked for, you'll need to modify your question.

Comment: I was looking for a function that asymptote at $0.5$, and pass through $(0,0.5)$. These 2 requirements (both stated in the original question) are not contradictory at all. In the question I also provide the code to make the cumulative Gaussian asymptote at 0.5. More generally, you can make any cumulative function asymptote at a given level $\gamma$ using this transformation $P(x)=\gamma + (1-\gamma)\Phi(x)$. This is quite common for some application, for example if you need to model the proportion of correct choices between $n$ alternatives, then the expected chance performance is $\gamma=1/n$

Comment: What is it you think asymptote means? Can you point to a definition?

Comment: in this context is the expected rate of correct choices at chance (when the signal, here delta, is too low and the observer is reduced to pure guessing). If the choice is between 2 alternative, the proportion of correct choices at chance will not asymptote at 0 but 0.5. There are several articles out there on the topic, [this is one](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03194552)

Comment: Let me clarify. The word "asymptote" really doesn't mean what you think it does. I asked what you thought it meant so that I could figure out how to briefly clarify what it does mean, rather than just referring you to the [wikipedia page on "Asymptote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote). Please take a look at it and correct any references to the term in your question so that your question is answerable. [Further, if you don't actually require a Gaussian, it probably shouldn't be prominently stated in your title.]

Answer (score 0):

I've been bothered by this problem for several years, so happy to find out I'm not the only one who cares about this. I just came up with this solution after read your discussion with Mark L. Stone:

- simply add the constraint of mu >= 3*sigma when finding the maximum likelihood. this is because ±3 standard deviation covers 99.7% of the area under the normal distribution. passing exactly the (0,0.5) point might not be possible (Glen_b does have a point). so, I feel this is close enough to what we want.

below is how I fit my psychometric function in matlab, using the maximum likelihood method

```
    %x(1)=mu, x(2)=sigma, x(3)=lamda
    %constraint: 3*sigma-mu<=0
    %data=[intensity;ncorrect;Ntotal]
    %likelihoodfunction = prod(binopdf(ncorrect,Ntotal,cdf('Normal',intensity,mu,sigma).*(1-2*lamda)/2+1/2))
    options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','MaxIterations',1500,'Display','iter-detailed');
    negloglikelihood=@(x) -sum(log(binopdf(data(:,2),data(:,3),cdf('Normal',data(:,1),x(1),x(2)).*(1-2*x(3))/2+1/2)));
    A=[-1,3,0];
    b=0;
    x = fmincon(negloglikelihood,start,A,b,[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

below is an example figure of the fit
[image]